# Where can I view all the alt-codes?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-code

Where can I view all the alt codes for Windows 10? I know I can look in Charmap, but some of the symbols in Charmap are mixed in with characters that don't have an alt-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt codes method allow input **ANY symbol** by it's code.
But by default, you can only input the first 256 characters. Codes bigger than 256 get wrapped around (try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0176</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0432</kbd>)

To enable the entry of all Unicode characters by code, create a string registry value in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad` with the value of 1. Then you'll be able to enter any character by:

1. holding down the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key,
2. pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the numeric keypad,
3. entering the hex code,
4. and releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

You may need to log off and back on before this input type is enabled.

Comment: It may seem dumb that I don't know this, but how can I find the hex codes? If I was typing in a character with the code U+0125, would I hold alt, press +, and 0125?